# convert timestamp to date time in php

Tags: php, timestamp

1517317337107

it should be: Wed Jan 31 00:02:17 GMT+11:00 2018

I verify this on https://www.epochconverter.com/

the result is:
Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds:
GMT: Tuesday, January 30, 2018 1:02:17.107 PM
Your time zone: Wednesday, January 31, 2018 12:02:17.107 AM GMT+11:00 DST

My code in php is:

```
$timestamp = 1517317337107;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

the output is "2038-01-19 04:14:07"

what should I do?

Comment: where 1517317337107 was from?

Answer (score 11):

That timestamp is in milliseconds, not seconds. Just divide it by 1000.

```
php > $timestamp = 1517317337107;
php > echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp/1000);
2018-01-30 05:02:17
```

Comment: My time zone is different from yours, hence the different rendered time, by the way.

Comment: Thank you, but how could I also convert this to the timezone "australia/sydney"?

Comment: That wasn't part of your question. But if you do `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');` before running the `date` function, it'll come out in that time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Convert Your timestamp in seconds and set timezone

```
$timestamp = 1517317337107;
$timestamp_in_seconds = $timestamp/1000;
date_default_timezone_set("Australia/Sydney");
echo date('D M d Y H:i:s', $timestamp_in_seconds);
```

> Output: Wed Jan 31 2018 00:02:17